# Pyinstaller/CXFreeze bundle keeps rerunning the project on an infinite loop on mac

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5, ipython, pyinstaller

I ran `pyinstaller --windowed --onedir Yuro.py` and through troubleshooting I realized that my ipython console causes this infinite loop and I do not know how to stop it. When I click the finished pyinstaller bundle the project keeps rerunning on an infinite loop.

This is my app window starter code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon('images/icons8-lion-96.png'))
    app.setApplicationName("YuroPy IDE")
    window = Window()
    screen = app.primaryScreen()
    size = screen.size()
    window.resize(round(size.width() - size.width()/20), round(size.height() - size.height()/7))
    qr = window.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    window.move(qr.topLeft())
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

and this is my ipython qtconsole code:

```
USE_KERNEL = 'python3'

def make_jupyter_widget_with_kernel():
    """Start a kernel, connect to it, and create a RichJupyterWidget to use it
    """
    kernel_manager = QtKernelManager(kernel_name=USE_KERNEL)
    kernel_manager.start_kernel()

    kernel_client = kernel_manager.client()
    kernel_client.start_channels()

    jupyter_widget = RichJupyterWidget()
    jupyter_widget.kernel_manager = kernel_manager
    jupyter_widget.kernel_client = kernel_client
    return jupyter_widget
```

I also tried using CXFreeze, I didn't receive any error but the bundle kept running infinitely. Is this normal? and if its not how do I cope with it. I also added `multiprocess.freeze_support()` but it didn't help! These are all my imports:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit, QWidget, QPlainTextEdit, QTabBar, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QMenuBar, QAction, QVBoxLayout, QToolBar, QToolButton, QMenu, QLineEdit, QTreeView, QFileSystemModel, QTabWidget, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QStyle, QAbstractItemView, QHBoxLayout, QSplitter, QLabel, QDesktopWidget, QStylePainter, QStyleOptionButton, QInputDialog, QFileDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence, QFont, QIcon, QFontMetrics, QTextCursor, QPainter, QColor, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QRect, pyqtSignal, QDir, Qt, QUrl, QSocketNotifier, QSize
from PyQt5 import QtSvg
from PyQt5.Qsci import QsciScintilla, QsciLexerPython, QsciLexerCSS, QsciLexerHTML, QsciLexerJavaScript, QsciLexerCustom, QsciAPIs
import PyQt5
from qtconsole.rich_jupyter_widget import RichJupyterWidget
from qtconsole.manager import QtKernelManager
from pathlib import Path
from pylint import lint
from pylint.reporters.text import TextReporter
import os
import re
#os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt5'
import subprocess
import sys
import shutil
import pickle
import threading
import webbrowser
import locale, pty, struct, termios
```

Comment: You need to post your code with the imports, otherwise it's hard for people to debug your code. Also note that in PyQT5, you only need to specify app.exec(). Plus I hope you know that you have to close all open windows for the program to stop.

Comment: I edited the question!

Comment: By infinite loop, do you mean that the app is in an infinite loop or that there is an infinite looping of the app being run over and over again?

Comment: Yes infinite looping of the apps executables (creates many copies of app)

Comment: Are you doing any multiprocessing then? Make sure the mp calls are in a if name = main and make sure multiprocess.freeze_support() is called before any calls have been made.